# CANNOT POST , can't reach nodejs from android

Tags: android, node.js

I can't reach my nodejs server from an androiapp endpoint.
The thing is that I can reach from others post, but not from a new one.

From this url I can reach:

```
            ApiClient.post("/v1/forgot", params,
                    new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(int arg0, Header[] arg1,
                                byte[] arg2, Throwable arg3) {
                            userMessage=("Password NOT RESET.\n Please check the email entered,\n"+userEmailEntered+"\nor try again later.");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), userMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(int arg0, Header[] arg1,
                                byte[] resp) {
                            String response = new String(resp);
                            try {
                                JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response);
                                String json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).toString();
                                final ResetPasswordResponse resetPasswordResponse = JsonUtils.parseJson(json, ResetPasswordResponse.class);

                                if (resetPasswordResponse.getStatus().equals("sent")){
                                userMessage=("Reset instructions sent to "+resetPasswordResponse.getEmail());
                                }else{
                                    userMessage=("The email account entered "+resetPasswordResponse.getEmail()+" is not recognized. Please check the email address entered");
                                }
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), userMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

            });
```

But I can't from the new resource and post that Im creating:

```
    Log.i("store", devRegId.toString());

    //TODO PROBLEM TO SEND REGISTRATION - cannot post
    ApiClient.post("/v1/device", params,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] resp) {
            String response = new String(resp);
            Log.i("store", response);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] resp, Throwable error) {
            Log.i("store", "NOT ok");
            Log.i("store", resp.toString());

            String response = new String(resp);
            Log.i("store", response);
        }
    });
```

And that it`s the client.post created:

```
private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

 public static void post(String url, RequestParamsCustom params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {

        client.post(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
    }
```

Server route:

```
app.post('/v1/device', function(req,res) {

    gcmDeviceRouter.storeDevice(req,res)

});
```

The server is running ok, I can access from other end point (web app, postman tool).

The error it`s this:

debug I/store﹕ NOT ok

debug I/store﹕ [B@235ae686

debug I/store﹕ Cannot POST /v1/device

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is your onFailure error message?

Comment: Sorry, now its eddited

Comment: This leads me to believe that you do not have a post route on your server that maps to "/v1/device".  Can you post your server code please

Comment: edited again, express framework on node js, everything fine in the server side. It`s just awkward